# Embedding Index out of range:

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I understand why this error usually occurs, which is that the input >= embedding_dim.
However in my case the torch.max(inputs) = embedding_dim - 1.

```
print('inputs: ', src_seq)
print('input_shape: ', src_seq.shape)
print(self.src_word_emb)
inputs:  tensor([[10,  6,  2,  4,  9, 14,  6,  2,  5,  0],
        [12,  6,  3,  8, 13,  2,  0,  1,  1,  1],
        [13,  8, 12,  7,  2,  4,  0,  1,  1,  1]])
input_shape: [3, 10]
Embedding(15, 512, padding_idx=1)
emb = self.src_word_emb(src_seq)
```

I try to get a transformer model to work and for some reason the encoder embedding only accepts inputs < embedding_dim_decoder, which does not make sense right?

Answer (score 1):

Found the error source! In the transformer model the encoder and decoder can be set up to share the same embedding weights. However, I had a translation task with one embedding for the decoder and one embedding for the encoder. In the code it initializes the weights via:

```
if emb_src_trg_weight_sharing:
            self.encoder.src_word_emb.weight = self.decoder.trg_word_emb.weight
```

Setting `emb_src_trg_weight_sharing` to false solved the issue!